# Count how many times an integer is appears in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm attempting to find a way to count the end of an integer and display the trailing value.  For example, I have the following table:

```
CREDIT
======
1051000
10000
2066
16000
```

I'd like to be able to count the amount of times '0' appears and end up with a result like the following

```
CREDIT              CntOccuranceVals
======              ======
1051000             3
10000               4
2066                0
16000               3
```

Now I have tried using a query that will find all of the '0', but the problem I'm facing is for the first row it returns 4 instead of three as it is searching the whole row and not the trailing.  This is what I've tried using to find the occurrence count

```
DECLARE @LongSequence INT(MAX)
DECLARE @FindSubString INT(MAX)
SET @LongSequence = CREDIT
SET @FindSubString = '0'
SELECT (LEN(@LongSequence) - LEN(REPLACE(@LongSequence, @FindSubString, '')))     CntReplacedVals,
(LEN(@LongSequence) - LEN(REPLACE(@LongSequence, @FindSubString, '')))/LEN(@FindSubString) CntOccuranceVals
```

Is there a way I can find only the trailing 0's and not the ones in the middle of the value?

EDIT: typo

Comment: In your example, Why is 1 the answer to 10000? There are 4 trailing 0's. Shouldn't answer be 4?

Comment: Sorry yes, that was a typo. It is indeed meant to be 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use Reverse and Patindex like this:

```
Declare @a Table (i int)
insert into @a
Select 123000
union
Select 123001
union
Select 100000
union
Select 123001

Select i, PatIndex('%[1-9]%',Reverse(Cast(i as Varchar(50)))) - 1  as  CntOccuranceVals
from @a
```

Comment: Can also use `'%[^0]%'`

Comment: And to demostrate the point @MartinSmith has made, [here is another fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48e5d/7)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I believe this has pretty much got me sorted out :)